# How to add inline CSS to dynamically created elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add inline CSS to the left and right messages that are generated, for example the left text is red and the right text is blue. (I know it's best to style in the CSS, but I'm testing something else). So I will have this HTML:

```
<ul class="messages">
  <li class="message left appeared">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text" style="color:red;">blabla</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="message right appeared">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text" style="color:blue;">blabla</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please see the code as reference for the functionality. Many thanks for your help.

```js
(function() {
  var Message;

  Message = function({
      text: text1,
      message_side: message_side1
    }) {
    this.text = text1;
    this.message_side = message_side1;
    this.draw = () => {
      var $message;
      $message = $($('.message_template').clone().html());
      $message.addClass(this.message_side).find('.text').html(this.text);
      $('.messages').append($message);
      return setTimeout(function() {
        return $message.addClass('appeared');
      }, 0);
    };
    return this;
  };

  $(function() {
    var getMessageText, message_side, sendMessage;
    message_side = 'right';
    getMessageText = function() {
      var $message_input;
      $message_input = $('.message_input');
      return $message_input.val();
    };
    sendMessage = function(text) {
      var $messages, message;
      if (text.trim() === '') {
        return;
      }
      $('.message_input').val('');
      $messages = $('.messages');
      message_side = message_side === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
      message = new Message({text, message_side});
      message.draw();
      return $messages.animate({
        scrollTop: $messages.prop('scrollHeight')
      }, 300);
    };
    $('.send_message').click(function(e) {
      return sendMessage(getMessageText());
    });
    $('.message_input').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) { // enter key
        return sendMessage(getMessageText());
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chat_window {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 440px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.messages {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 347px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.messages .message {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.left .text_wrapper::before {
  right: 100%;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.left .text,
.messages .message.right .text {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.right .text_wrapper::before {
  left: 100%;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.appeared {
  opacity: 1;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message .text_wrapper:before {
  top: 18px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after {
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::before {
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbdc0;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper .message_input {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: absolute;
  outline-width: 0;
  color: gray;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.message_template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat_window">
  <ul class="messages"></ul>
  <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="message_input_wrapper">
      <input class="message_input" placeholder="Type here..." />
    </div>
    <div class="send_message">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
        Send
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message_template">
  <li class="message">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("li.message.left > div.text_wrapper > p").css('color', 'red');
$("li.message.right > div.text_wrapper > p").css('color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add:

```
$(".left").css("color", "yellow");
$(".right").css("color", "blue");
```

Comment: This one works! But is it possible to add a selector so for example instead of just `.left`, have `.left .text` or `.left p`? Thank you

Comment: It seems to work only if I select the the text and not the container left or right.

Comment: @redibis You mean to select children? Yes you can navigate the tree by adding child selectors > $(".left p") see: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ also mulptiple selectors are sepearated by comma $(".left, .right, .custom")

Comment: @redibis I can,t see the program working, if you post the full code I can check but I hope this answer explains how to select the elements using jQuery.

Comment: sorry should be : .left > p

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can add inline style to an element

```
$(".left").attr("style","whatever");
$(".right").attr("style","whatever");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `classList` of every HTML component. Simply, select the DOM element with class `left` (or `right`) and use the `add` method to assign whatever class:

```
var elementLeft = $('.left')
elementLeft.classList.add('yourClass')
```

You can also use the methods `remove` to remove any class, or `toggle` to toggle some class..

```
elementLeft.classList.remove('yourClass')
elementLeft.classList.toggle('yourClass')
```

The [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) contains more examples. This solution works without jQuery or others javascript library, but use the standard API.